# null checking error when checking a shared value from form2 in form 1

Tags: vb.net, winforms, parent-child

I am showing form2 on the keypress of datagrid in form1.heres the form 1 code

```
 Public Shared searchbox As TextBox
Private Sub datagridItems_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles datagridItems.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            If datagridItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                searchbox = datagridItems.CurrentCell.Value
                frmitemsearch.ShowDialog()

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am checking the value of searchbox in form 2 if theres any value or not,but in form2 its giving error on this line

```
Private Sub item_search_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim searchstr As String
If IsNothing(frmgrn.searchbox.Text) Then

            searchstr = ""
        Else
            searchstr = frmgrn.searchbox.Text
        End If
is nothing fails also I tried this 
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(frmgrn.searchbox.text) Then
```

..still it throws the nullexception error..i am confused about what I am doing wrong here... as 
I am  checking whether theres value or not and then execute the code.

Comment: Where does `Form2` get a reference to `frmgrn`?

Comment: it shows null reference exception was handled

Comment: hi david form2 gets a reference in the form load event.

Comment: Right.  And on that line either `frmgrn` or `frmgrn.searchbox` is clearly `null`.  Which one is it?  And where does that variable come from?  How does the form load event initialize that variable?

Comment: public shared searchbox is the variable in form1. I am accessing it in form2 in the following way..the formname.variablename.text.is it right eg.frmgrn.searchbox.text. the code in form2 is as follows  If frmgrn.searchbox.Text = String.Empty Then

            searchstr = ""
        Else
            searchstr = frmgrn.searchbox.Text
        End If

Comment: I'm afraid vague descriptions of what your code is doing aren't really helpful.  The error is manifesting on the line of code you've shown, but the cause of the problem exists elsewhere.  Either `frmgrn` or `frmgrn.searchbox` isn't being initialized properly or when you expect it to be.  But if you won't show that code, then you're on your own for debugging it.

Comment: `searchbox` looks ok in what is there...but how does the second form know what `frmgrn` is??  is there code like `frmgrn = ...`.  THAT seems to be missing.  Hold your mouse over the statement and it will tell you one of them is Nothing

Comment: heres the form2 load event... Private Sub item_search_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'POS_SYSTEMDataSet.POS_ITEM_MST' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        'AppsCon.Open()
        'Me.POS_ITEM_MSTTableAdapter.Fill(Me.POS_SYSTEMDataSet.POS_ITEM_MST)
    
        Dim searchstr As String
       
        If frmgrn.searchbox.Text.Length = 0 Then

            searchstr = ""
        Else
            searchstr = frmgrn.searchbox.Text
        End If

Comment: edit your question to add that...too hard to read in a comment (but I do not see any ref to frmGrn!)

Comment: hi david..can u correct it,i edited the question and the formatting is gone

Comment: @vimalvasudevan: You're still not showing where the variable `frmgrn` is initialized.  If it's never being initialized then, as a reference type, its default value is `null`.  That's the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is throwing a `NullReferenceException`:

```
If IsNothing(frmgrn.searchbox.Text) Then
```

Because this variable is `null`:

```
frmgrn
```

You're not initializing that variable anywhere in your code.  (At least not in the code you've shown us.)  I'm going to assume for a moment, based on its use, that `frmgrn` is a class-level variable in `Form2`.  Something like this:

```
Private frmgrn as Form1
```

This doesn't initialize the variable.  It just creates a reference to hold it.

However, beyond just initializing it, in this case you need it to not only be initialized but you need it to *specifically* refer to the instance of `Form1` that's already loaded.  An easy way to do this is for `Form1` to pass a reference for itself to `Form2` when it creates an instance of `Form2`.  You're referencing that instance here:

```
frmitemsearch.ShowDialog()
```

Notice, however, that you also haven't shown how `frmitemsearch` gets initialized.  I'm going to assume it's something like this:

```
Dim frmitemsearch as New Form2()
```

In this case you can create a new constructor for `Form2` which accepts a reference to an instance of `Form1`:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal form1 As Form1)
    frmgrn = form1
End Sub
```

This would initialize that (assumed) class-level member (`frmgrn`) when an instance of `Form2` is created, setting it to whatever is passed to the constructor.  So you'd call the new constructor like this:

```
Dim frmitemsearch as New Form2(Me)
```

At this point when you create an instance of `Form2`, you'd be giving it an existing instance of `Form1`.  It would store that instance in a class-level variable.  Then any time you have code like this on `Form2`:

```
If IsNothing(frmgrn.searchbox.Text) Then
```

you would be referencing an actual instance of `frmgrn` instead of just an empty reference.

Comment: also I am getting confused with datasets, data adapter, data reader. could you please suggest some helpful articles/blogs P.S: just started programming in vb.net so trying to understand these concepts

Comment: @vimalvasudevan: That's a very broad topic.  But in general what you're talking about is using ADO.NET as a data access technology.  This MSDN article should be a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx